# Copy and paste to or from google colab terminal

Tags: google-colaboratory

Is it possible to copy and paste to/from the Google Colab terminal?
I tried to copy by 'ctrl +c' but this does not copy the text.
Alternatively I tried to copy by right clicking on the terminal, but this shows the normal browser pop up menu without copy/paste.

[image: clipping of terminal]

Answer (score 2):

for the paste operation we can use the shortkey below like unix terminal: Shift+Ctrl+V

but the copy operation can not be done by Shift+Ctrl+C